# using a conditional and lambda in map

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, conditional-statements

If I want to take a list of numbers and do something like this:

```
lst = [1,2,4,5]
[1,2,4,5] ==> ['lower','lower','higher','higher']
```

where `3` is the condition using the map function, is there an easy way?

Clearly `map(lambda x: x<3, lst)` gets me pretty close, but how could I include a statement in map that allows me to immediately return a string instead of the booleans?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
>>> lst = [1,2,4,5]
>>> map(lambda x: 'lower' if x < 3 else 'higher', lst)
['lower', 'lower', 'higher', 'higher']
```

Aside: It's usually preferred to use a list comprehension for this

```
>>> ['lower' if x < 3 else 'higher' for x in lst]
['lower', 'lower', 'higher', 'higher']
```

Comment: ya I figured how to do it with a list comprehension no problem but for some reason kept getting errors when I used if statements in my map.  Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: for future reference... this will not work for `numpy.array` use [`numpy.where`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34381847/valueerror-when-trying-to-apply-lambda-expression-to-elements-of-an-array)

Comment: So others know for compatibility, this seems to have been added in Python 2.5 with [conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/2.7/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-308-conditional-expressions). This isn't available in Python 2.3 that I'm using.

Comment: @JoshDetwiler,open option for Python2.3 is this `[('higher', 'lower')[x < 3] for x in lst]`. It's harder to read though, and evaluates both options (doesn't really matter here as they are just strings)

Comment: Is it necessary to have an else clause in the conditional? My code does not work without specifying the else clause.

Comment: @Ansh, it that form it is a ternary - so needs all 3 parts. You can write the condition at the end in the usual way if you wish to filter `['lower' for x in lst if x < 3]`

Answer (score 2):

Ternary operator:

```
map(lambda x: 'lower' if x<3 else 'higher', lst)
```