# ValueError while applying lambda expression to elements of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, lambda, runtime-error

Currently I faced an error while processing a numpy.array - 4x1 - i.e

```
[[-1.96113883]
 [-3.46144244]
 [ 5.075857  ]
 [ 1.77550086]]
```

with the lambda function `f = lambda x: x if (x > 0) else (x * 0.01)`.

The error is `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`.

I searched through the different topics here on stackoverflow.com but I have not find any satisfactory explanation of the problem and a case that suited mine (many unclear references to the `and` operator, vectorized code etc.).

What I expect after processing the array is an array of the same dimensions of the input one and each single value modified according to the function, which for the example would be:

```
[[-0.0196113883]
 [-0.0346144244]
 [ 5.075857  ]
 [ 1.77550086]]
```

Finally, can someone please provide me a solution and the explanation about why this error occurred. Thank you in advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x > 0` is evaluated for your numpy array as a whole, returning another array of booleans. However, the `if` statement evaluates the whole array as a single operation.

```
arr = np.array([[-1.96113883],
                [-3.46144244],
                [ 5.075857  ],
                [ 1.77550086]])
print arr > 0
   [[False]
    [False]
    [ True]
    [ True]]
```

As stated in the error message, the truth value of an array of booleans is ambigous.

Instead, as noted by ajcr in the comments, you should use `np.where` for a vectorized `if-else` statement

E.g.

```
np.where(arr > 0, arr, arr*0.01)
array([[-0.01961139],
       [-0.03461442],
       [ 5.075857  ],
       [ 1.77550086]])
```

Comment: For vectorized if/else operations, it's fastest/best-practice to try and use `np.where`, e.g. `np.where(arr > 0, arr, arr*0.01)`.

Comment: Thanks for the improvement. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried with `np.vectorize` and it works. However what are the pros and cons of using `np.vectorize` or `np.where` (of course the use of the latter is specifically related to the fact that is a `if-else`)? What would you suggest if I have to process the elements of an array using other functions?

Comment: `np.vectorize` is more generic and can be used as `map`, but inside a numpy array. However, it does use an extra function call for each element, which is avoided in the case of `np.where`.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to apply your lambda function to the whole array, but what you want is to apply it to every element. There are more numpy-y solutions to this. Let your array be `a` and `numpy` be imported as `np`. You could use fancy indexing:

```
>>> a_leq_0 = a <= 0
>>> a[a_leq_0] = a[a_leq_0]*0.01
>>> a
array([[-0.01961139],
       [-0.03461442],
       [ 5.075857  ],
       [ 1.77550086]])
```

or even better `np.where`:

```
>>> np.where(a > 0, a, a*0.01)
array([[-0.01961139],
       [-0.03461442],
       [ 5.075857  ],
       [ 1.77550086]])
```

The explanation is in the docs of `where`:

> where(condition, [x, y])
>   [...]
>   If both `x` and `y` are specified, the output array contains elements of `x` where `condition` is True, and elements from
>           `y` elsewhere.

Comment: I have not downvoted your reply indeed I have not gained the possibility to vote yet. In any case, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using directly a comprehension list:

```
np.array([list(i*0.01) if i>0 else list(i) for i in arr])

Out[28]: 
array([[-1.96113883],
       [-3.46144244],
       [ 0.05075857],
       [ 0.01775501]])
```

**Data**

```
arr = np.array([[-1.96113883],
 [-3.46144244],
 [ 5.075857  ],
 [ 1.77550086]])
```

Comment: This yields a python list of numpy arrays and does not meet the requirements.

Comment: Now it yields a list of lists and still does not meet the requirements. You need to cast everything back to array once more.